# SELECT DISTINCT not working with INNER JOIN and ORDER BY newid()

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, sql-order-by, inner-join

I am trying to query a database of Wines and Wineries, to get 4 random wines from **different** wineries. Unfortunately, I still see some duplicate wineries in my results and adding "DISTINCT" to my query doesn't work with the `newid()` function. I have also tried "GROUP BY" and Sub queries with no solution. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT TOP(4) w.ID_Winery, w.appellation, w.delete_wine, w.Description_brief, w.wine_vintage, a.ID_Winery, a.weblogin, a.Winery, a.WebSiteUrl 
FROM Wines w
INNER JOIN Wineries a
    ON w.ID_Winery = a.ID_Winery
WHERE w.appellation = 'Lorem Ipsum'
    AND a.weblogin !=""
    AND w.delete_wine !=1
    AND a.Winery = 1
    AND a.WebSiteUrl !=""
    AND a.okWinery = "yes"
    AND w.Description_brief
        LIKE '%Lorem Ipsum%'
ORDER BY newid()
```

Comment: If you called you mechanic and said "my car isn't working, how do I fix it" would they be able to give you an answer, @qwerty123 ..? No, and neither can we; "doesn't work' means nothing to us as it doesn't **explain** the problem. We aren't mind readers.

Comment: Ok, let me clarify a bit more for you. I want 4 wines from DIFFERENT wineries. It is not working, which means I am getting duplicate wineries in my query results. Can you recommend any changes to my query which might help me get 4 wines from DIFFERENT wineries?

Comment: `DISTINCT` *cannot* return duplicate rows, @user3826864 . By "duplicates" do you mean you are getting 2, or more, **different** wines fr the same winery? Perhaps what you really want is a "TOP 1 per group", and then a "random" result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT TOP 4 *
FROM (
    SELECT w.ID_Winery, w.appellation, w.delete_wine, w.Description_brief, 
        w.wine_vintage, a.ID_Winery, a.weblogin, a.Winery, a.WebSiteUrl,
        row_number() over (partition by w.ID_Winery order by newid()) rn
    FROM Wines w
    INNER JOIN Wineries a
        ON w.ID_Winery = a.ID_Winery
    WHERE w.appellation = 'Lorem Ipsum'
        AND a.weblogin !=""
        AND w.delete_wine !=1
        AND a.Winery = 1
        AND a.WebSiteUrl !=""
        AND a.okWinery = "yes"
        AND w.Description_brief
            LIKE '%Lorem Ipsum%'
) t
WHERE rn=1
ORDER BY newid()
```

FWIW, I'm [not a fan of ordering by newid.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/03/get-random-row-large-table/)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! Unfortunately, I get an error: "The column 'ID_Winery' was specified multiple times for 't'"

Comment: Just take either w.ID_Winery or a.ID_Winery out of the sub-query and then you shouldn't get that particular error

Comment: Thank you, I created aliases for each of the ID_Winery columns and fixed the error: